# How do I access local resources on a remote webpage with CefSharp?

Tags: c#, javascript, cefsharp

I've been looking all over the place but I can't get CefSharp to load from a `file://` URL. to work. This is what I have right now.

```
BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed = true;
browserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed = true;
browserSettings.DeveloperToolsDisabled = false;


this.webview = new WebView("http://google.com", browserSettings);
```

As you can see, I have `FileAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed` and `UniversalAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed` set to true.

I'm trying to add a local image to the DOM with Javascript:

```
this.webview.ExecuteScript(@"
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src','file:///C:/test.jpg');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img);
");
```

It doesn't work; when I open up the developer console, this error pops up

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/test.jpg`

I've been trying to figure this out all day, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See Q&A in this CefSharp Google Group thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cefsharp/4gxmKwrhDSU/V71BSQdEroMJ

Answer (score 0):

Answering a fairly old question in case my solution helps anyone else.

I experienced a similar problem with "Not allowed to load local resource:" where I believed I had everything setup correctly. I finally realized some of my files were not getting copied to the build output directory due to not configuring my project correctly in Visual Studio. After adding the html, js, etc. files, I forgot to set the properties on a file 'Copy to Output' = 'Copy if newer'. The error message is a bit misleading since the problem was due to a file not being found.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question, but it just happened to me and I came up to a solution. Just in case it helps someone you can load local resources if you add the next line:

browserSettings.LocalStorage = CefState.Enabled;